# C# OleDbQuery is too complex

Tags: c#, oledb

I've been trying to find way speed up this query

I am using OleDb to get data from a excel file

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count){
sql = "SELECT SUM([Freeze Qty]), SUM([Count Qty]) FROM [00000604$] 
    WHERE [Item Code]='" + list[y] + "'"
   while(reader.read){
     getData.freezeCounts.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
     getData.actualCount.Add(reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
  }

}
```

the query above loops through a list of item codes and sum's the freeze qty for the items codes so if they item codes are in there more than once they will get added together added to an array some for count qty

I have tried this but the query to complex error

```
SELECT SUM([Freeze Qty]), SUM([Count Qty]) FROM [00000604$] 
WHERE [Item Code]='11792'
UNION SELECT SUM([Freeze Qty]), SUM([Count Qty]) FROM [00000604$] 
WHERE [Item Code] = '11988' 
UNION SELECT SUM([Freeze Qty]), SUM([Count Qty]) FROM [00000604$] 
WHERE [Item Code] = '11994'
```

Comment: Can you run that query against excel via some other way and see if it works or not? I suspect it's Excel's... whatever database engine it uses that throws that error, not a C# OleDb issue.

Comment: Anyway see if you can translate this to OleDb: `SELECT [Item Code], SUM([Freeze Qty]) FROM blah WHERE [Item Code] IN '` and here you have a list e.g. `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) GROUP BY [Item Code]`

Comment: Thank you very much GROUP BY [Item Code] worked a treat